# Multiple Select queries in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, union

I have a table as such.

```
home team | away team | attendance | home or away|
       SD |        WP |    SD OVAL |        4000 | H |
       WP |        SD |    SD OVAL |        4000 | A |
```

I want to be able to generate one table to display as such

```
Team  | Home Total  | Home Average | Away Total | Away Average | Total | Average |
  SD  |       4000  |         4000 |          0 |           0  |  4000 |    4000 |
  WP  |          0  |            0 |       4000 |        4000  |  4000 |    4000 |
```

I have tried joins and union, although UNION gives me the best result, although the results are returned in only three columns

```
Team, HomeAttendance, AveHomeAttendance
```

This is my query (I am still new in MYSQL)

```
SELECT Team,
       SUM(Attendance) AS HomeAttendance,
       ROUND(AVG(Attendance),0) AS AveHomeAttendance
FROM MatchDetails
WHERE Season = 2014
  AND HA = 'H'
GROUP BY TEAM
UNION
SELECT Team,
       SUM(Attendance) AS AwayAttendance,
       ROUND(AVG(Attendance),0) AS AveAwayAttendance
FROM MatchDetails
WHERE Season = 2014
  AND HA = 'A'
GROUP BY TEAM
UNION
SELECT Team,
       SUM(Attendance) AS TotalAttendance,
       ROUND(AVG(Attendance),0) AS AveTotalAttendance
FROM MatchDetails
WHERE Season = 2014
GROUP BY TEAM
```

Comment: What do you want in the `home or away` column?  You list both teams in each record, so what does this field mean?

Comment: The objective of the table is to list the total and average attendance for each team over a season.  The home or away column in the table is populate with an 'H' for a Home game and an 'A' for an away game.

Comment: But is the attendance only really associated with the home team? I mean there is alway only one home team, so why the home or away column? What does that really mean?

Comment: the first query is to calculate the total home and average home attendance for each team, the second query the away total and average for each team, and the third query the total and average attendance for each team.

Comment: in my table the attendance is associate with both the home and away team.  ie one record is team a v team b at venue a attendance:4000, Home or Away: H. The next record in my table is team b v team a at venue a attendance: 4000 Home or Away: A

Comment: But how do you know which team is referred to in the home or away column? Depending on which team you are interest in, that value should could change.  Where I am going with this, is that I think you have confused yourself with a bad schema.

Comment: each game in my database is included on two rows, the first is for the home team the second row is for the away team. Each row I capture the team, opponent, attendance and HA (Home or Away) - so the first row is for the home team, the second the away team.  doe that help?

Comment: I've update the question with sample data - no idea how to format is nicely though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your update, you could use `JOIN` instead of `UNION`:

```
   SELECT total.HomeTeam AS Team,
          IFNULL(SUM(home.Attendance),0) AS HomeAttendance,
          IFNULL(ROUND(AVG(home.Attendance),0),0) AS AveHomeAttendance,
          IFNULL(SUM(away.Attendance),0) AS AwayAttendance,
          IFNULL(ROUND(AVG(away.Attendance),0),0) AS AveAwayAttendance,
          IFNULL(SUM(total.Attendance),0) AS TotalAttendance,
          IFNULL(ROUND(AVG(total.Attendance),0),0) AS AveTotalAttendance
     FROM MatchDetails total
LEFT JOIN MatchDetails home
       ON home.id = total.id AND home.HA = 'H'
LEFT JOIN MatchDetails away
       ON away.id = total.id AND away.HA = 'A'
    WHERE total.Season = 2014
 GROUP BY total.HomeTeam;
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/41a57/3)

Comment: brilliant Prix - that worked a treat - thanks heaps :)